# Heroku + MiniMagick + ImageMagick error loading libraries

Tags: heroku, imagemagick, minimagick

I am on Heroku using a RoR app.

I am using carrierwave and with mini_magick (imagemagick).

Everything works fine on my local server.

On heroku I get the following error:

```
Icon Failed to manipulate with MiniMagick, maybe it is not an image? Original Error: `identify /tmp/mini_magick20181115-4-12nnpxw.png` failed with error: identify: error while loading shared libraries: libdjvulibre.so.21: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It seems libdjvulibre.so.21 is not present. I have added the buildpack for imagemagick: https://github.com/ello/heroku-buildpack-imagemagick

Any suggestions?

Comment: What was the command that failed? If you call convert in mini-magick, then perhaps you need to provide the full path to convert.

Comment: I'm hitting this as well on a heroku-18 stack, with both imagemagick and image-optim buildpacks in place using carrierwave. I have a variety of versions that are using the following directives:

    process :resize_to_fit => [400, 400]
    process :convert => 'jpg'
    process optimize: [{ quality: 60 }]

Comment: devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages libdjvulibre-21 is installed as a package on heroku stacks, but it's only available at build time, not runtime.

Comment: fmw42 - specific command that fails (and it does so at the command line as well) is `identify`.

Comment: If mini-magics is using ImageMagick 7, then "identify" is replace by "magick identify" and "convert" is replace by "magick"

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so after contacting support ("we don't deal with third party build packs") and lots of help from some friends, the solution is frustratingly simple (on heroku-18 stacks):

Delete the build pack.

Unless you need a different version than what ships (https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack-packages), which is `8:6.9.7.4​+dfsg-16​ubuntu6.4`, then just remove the pack. This worked for me on my staging environment.